How to change folding icon position in mxgraph
I am trying to create a graph of stacked children's for compact layout behaviour using tree chart.
With the below configuration, it looks stacked.
var layout = new mxCompactTreeLayout(graph, true);

But, the folding icon is still at the bottom centre and hence the right hand side node edges are not properly aligned.
If the folding icon is on RHS vertically aligned, then it would look aligned.
Looking for something similar like Treantjs here

and like this:

Is it possible to achieve with mxgraph? Looking forward to see the configuration settings to achieve this with an example.
